# Countblank in excel up to a certain row

Tags: excel, count, countif

I have an array of unsorted numbers and blank cells, and I would like to count the number of blanks within the entire column, but I would like to restrict this to a range up to and including a specific row number. This is because I will be adding more data to my excel file in the coming months and I would like this automatically update. Is there a way that I can restrict the row where countblank stops dynamically? If need be I would not have a problem with doing this using a specific value not necessarily the row where that value is if it's easier.

Here is a portion of my array. I have a / where there are blanks.

```
1   
2
3
/    
/
5
/
13
2
/
7
/
7
6
/
64
```

In this example I would like to have the counting stop at the last 7. My real array is significantly longer though and I will be stopping somewhere in the middle.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excel formula to do this.

```
=COUNTBLANK(range)
```

Please [see the documentation for details](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTBLANK-function-6a92d772-675c-4bee-b346-24af6bd3ac22). You can set a dynamic range based on whatever criteria you need.

Comment: Please read my question again. Countblank does not work, I even mention the function in my question. I want a countblank"if" where I control where it stops counting.

Comment: Your question is unclear then. Why can you not just specify a range?

Comment: I cannot specify simply specify a range because the length of the range will change. I am going to be adding more values in as time goes on. I thought I said that. I will correct it if I didn't.

Comment: I think you're assuming a range must be static? A range can be dynamic, and you can define what that criteria is however you need it to.

[See this article for details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830287/how-to-create-a-dynamic-defined-range-in-an-excel-worksheet).

If this is not the case, please update your question to describe what your range limitations are.